# Debian Segmentation Fault

Tags: bashrc, segmentation-fault

After editing .bashrc I had "Segmentation fault" as an error.
This is what I added to bashrc:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ];
then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -l'

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
        . /etc/bash_completion
fi

PS1="\[\e[1;37m\](\#) \[\e[1;33m\]\D{%H:%M:%S} \[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[1;31m\]\u\[\e[1;36m\]@\h:\[\e[1;32m\]\w\[\e[1;35m\]#\[\e[m\] "

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

Then I executed `bash` to reload profile :

```
~$ bash
Segmentation fault
```

For information, I am using :

```
~$ cat /etc/debian_version 
7.7
```

Another thing, my bashrc is not loaded. Example:

```
~$ ll /etc/
-bash: ll: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning you are recursively sourcing `~/.bashrc`.  You probably wanted to include `/etc/bashrc` instead.  As a result bash terminates with stack overflow during parsing.